# Capturing the place autocomplete for two fields..!

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know how to use the google maps place autocomplete for a single field in a form; But what if i want to use the same functionality for more than two fields like i have to fill the Source and Destination Addresses..!! Help me out..!!!

And the actual place autocomplete can be found over here: `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete`

The actual problem is, that API uses the id of the textbox/field. So, one form cannot have more than one field with the same name, so, stucked up at this..!! Help me out..!!!

Comment: The API doesn't use the ID, it uses a reference to an input-element. It doesn't matter how you provide the reference. You must create a single Autocomplete-instance for each field.

Comment: It matters how we provide the REFERENCE.!!! And that is only through ID's.. The good part of the API is, it allows us to register n number of Id's to get with the work in an ease.. :)

Comment: When it matters and when it's only possible via IDs, how can this fiddle work: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/NhqDc/ ? There is no element with an ID